# Trying to identify a young adults fantasy book

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

I'm looking for a book that a friend loaned me in Junior High. It was about a group of friends trying to take down an evil wizard. The most I can remember is that at the end of the book they have a showdown with the wizard on top of his tower, they lose and decide to split up. One of the characters dreams of being a wizard but is of a race that can't do magic, at the end of the book he discovers he is able to do a kind of rainbow magic that he doesn't understand. Any help would be appreciated, been looking for years!

Additional info: It was sword/sorcery and at least the main character was human. The group was mixed in gender. The rainbow magic character came from a race that was very short and the rainbow magic came out of his fingers. There were other forms of magic but unfortunately I can't remember them, it's been a long time. Thanks again

Comment: This is very generic. Can you recall [any more details](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)? Who were the friends? Where were they friends from? What race was the would-be wizard? Were they adults, teens? Were they all male, all female, mixed? What races were the others? What were their names? What setting was it (sword/sorcery, Medieval, Urban)? Why were they trying to stop the wizard? Did he have any henchmen? What was the his name? How did magic work in this world? What form did the "rainbow magic" take? Were there other kinds of magic?

Comment: What did the magic do when it came out of his fingers? Was it like a ray-gun? Did the evil wizard use some kind of light-based magic?

Comment: http://www.barnesandnoble.com/w/the-un-magician-christopher-golden/1012365346#productInfoTabs?

Comment: I can't remember anything past that, unfortunately :( It wasn't "The Unmagician" though, thank you!

Comment: Leprechaun race? Very short, rainbows, hmm

Comment: It sounds a bit like *Willow*, but it was a film. Maybe there was a novelization?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### *Return of the Sorceress*

This is the fourth book in the Dragonlance New Adventures series, set in the D&D setting created by Margaret Weis and Tracy Hicks, but written by a number of other authors.

The race without magical ability (or fear) are kender, a hobbit-like or gnome-like species. The one you mention is Sindri Suncatcher, who can indeed produce rainbow magic from his fingers.

> Sindri stretched his hand toward the pond and a beam of sunlight struck his silver ring in such a way that, for an instant, it shone with the multicolored light of a rainbow. Then the surface of the water began to bubble in a half-dozen places, and then six medium-sized fish rose into the air.

This later turns out to be a sort of wild magic that causes a number of issues.

The evil wizard is Maddoc, who seeks to use the power of the ancient sorceress Asvoria for his own ends. She may have other plans, though...